# Deleting and replacing sheet on opening breaks in cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, reference, worksheet

it's me, again.

I have a code that import a reference sheet on wb_open. Im trying something new to get my code faster but it's creating a problem.

My new code delete (instead of copi-pasting) the existing internal Ref sheet and replace is by the external (refreshed or not) one.

The problem comes from the fact that deleting the internal ref sheet deletes my in-cell reference to that sheet even tho im naming the newly copied sheet the exact same name. Is there a way to get around?

```
Sub Workbook_open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Sheetname As String
Sheetname = "cédule détaillée 2 "

Worksheets(Sheetname).Visible = True

Dim externalwb As Workbook
Set externalwb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:="\\Backup\Opérations\Coaticook\Planification\Cédule détaillées\Cédule détaillées des composantes.xlsx")

Dim curentSheetNumber As Long
currentSheetNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname).Index
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname).Delete
externalwb.Worksheets(Sheetname).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheetNumber - 1)
externalwb.Close False

Worksheets(Sheetname).Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

       
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And where is the problem?  Do you receive an error? It should no matter if you delete the sheet and the sheet name doesn't matter, also, since `curentSheetNumber` received a value before the sheet deletion. It will raise an error only if the sheet in discussion (the deleted one) was the first one...

Comment: The problem is that the in-cell formulas use reference to `sheetname` and since im deleting it they become `#ref`, my code initialy copie pasted all external ref sheets onto internal ref sheet, it was working but using a lot more lines

Comment: Understood now what you mean... I did not think about formulas. At least, I did not see any reference in your question, from this point of view. Are there  many (different) such formulas on the page? If not, they can be rewritten in code, after your copy - paste operation.

Comment: is it 5 column on 9 pages, but its only 5 fomulas total (same page 9 time, formulas being drag down on different row) it would be effectively possible for me to re-right is but the formulas are huge

Comment: It is very simple actually.. let me test the code before posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the next formula copying approach, please:

```
Sub testCopyFormulas()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngForm As Range, shN As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set rngForm = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
   Set shN = Worksheets.Add

   shN.Range(rngForm.Address).Formula = rngForm.Formula
End Sub
```

And specifically in your code, try this approach:

```
'...your code...
 Dim externalwb As Workbook, rngForm As Range
 Set externalwb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:="\\Backup\Opérations\Coaticook\Planification\Cédule détaillées\Cédule détaillées des composantes.xlsx")

 Dim curentSheetNumber As Long
 Set rngForm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
 currentSheetNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname).Index
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname).Delete
 externalwb.Worksheets(Sheetname).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheetNumber - 1)
 externalwb.Close False
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(rngForm.Address).Formula = rngForm.Formula
 '...Your code...
```

Comment: `Set rngForm = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` You hit the nail on the head :)